# App fonts changed when running from Xcode 8

Tags: ios, fonts, ios9, xcode7, xcode8-beta2

I have designed my storyboard in `Xcode 7` and it's looking fine across all devices. I set the fonts from Interface Builder but when I run the app from `Xcode 8 beta` in `iOS 9.x`, the `button's` and `label's` fonts are changed automatically. Is it a bug in `Xcode 8 beta`? Also, is there any way to fix this issue without changing every components fonts manually?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue in Xcode 8 release with iOS 10.  In the app built for iOS 10 in Xcode 8 running on iOS 9.3 both simulator and on a real device 6plus the font size decreases in size. Oddly enough running on an iPad 
Running the same build in iOS 10 everything is fine.
This is a iPhone app, not universal.

[Edit] - If I check Check the "Selectable" checkbox in the xib attribute inspector the problem goes away. This is for a read-only UITextView.
Interesting.